# mlockall on AIX 5.3

Tags: c++, memory, permissions, aix

I have the problem that mlockall returns with unpriviledged users(every user other than root) directly with -1 the application which i used to run this was from the Stackoverflow site: [What happens when you run out of ram with mlockall set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190579/what-happens-when-you-run-out-of-ram-with-mlockall-set)

Now my issue is, there is that i dont know the AIX 5.3 command. There is a command in solaris usermod -K defaultpriv=basic,proc_lock_memory user, i cannot remember the article but it was also on stackoverflow, now i'am trying to find the equivalent for AIX 5.3 and how i can give permission to a user so that mlockall can be used.

Has Anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIX5.3 (and later) requires the the process to have root (either setuid root or real root).

[See manpage here.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/mlockall.htm)

"The calling process must have the root user authority to use this subroutine."

Comment: Thanks alot, i actually read the man page but just partially, woops.